# Working with XML & PHP/MYSQL Data

Tags: xml

I have some PHP & MySQL programming knowledge but need some guidance on how to do the following.

I have an xml feed from existing website/service. Can anyone suggest or tell me how I would go about taking the data from XML feed and storing it in my database (ideally would like to update database content every hour due to XML feed updates hourly).

My intention is to create a mini game that uses the information from the XML feed.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In brief, you need, apparently to retrieve the data feed, parse it, then iterate over the list of elements, and record the data to your database.

There are a number of ways how to retrieve the XML from a remote service. You can use [`cURL`](http://php.net/curl) or [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) for instance. The best choice, in long term perspective, probably would be some wrapper library for cURL.

To work with XML you have two main options: [`DOM`](http://php.net/DOM) and [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/SimpleXML). As you need only to read, SimpleXML will suite you better.

I assume you should know how to work with a database, so I'll omit this.

To automatically execute a script periodically you can setup a [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on a Unix-like OS or use any other job scheduler.